# PineScript Array "Index is out of bounds"

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am attempting a very simple array and am encountering the following error when I call     the 'array.clear()' function and attempt to create the new label "CCI1H End"

"In 'array.get()' function. Index 2 is out of bounds, array size is 0"

The following code is an attempt to check if the last of the 3 sequential CCI pivot highs is the highest and if CCI drops below 50 then I want to clear the array and begin the count again. I tried several different arrangements and ended with this nested arrangement thinking I could contain it within a local scope to no avail. Please help, I barely know what I'm doing and would be very appreciative of an assist.

Here is the code:

```
var CCI1H = array.new_float(3)

if cci > 50 
    if (cciPeakPivotHigh > 100)
        array.push(CCI1H, cciPeakPivotHigh)
        array.shift(CCI1H)
        CCI1Hval1 = array.get(CCI1H, 2)
        CCI1Hval2 = array.get(CCI1H, 1)
        CCI1Hval3 = array.get(CCI1H, 0)
        if array.size(CCI1H) == 3 and (CCI1Hval3 > CCI1Hval2 and CCI1Hval3 > CCI1Hval1)
            label.new(bar_index, na, "CCI1H End", yloc = yloc.abovebar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal)

else if cci < 50 
    array.clear(CCI1H)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
var CCI1H = array.new_float(0)

if cci > 50 
    if (cciPeakPivotHigh > 100)
        array.push(CCI1H, cciPeakPivotHigh)
        if array.size(CCI1H) == 3
            CCI1Hval1 = array.get(CCI1H, 2)
            CCI1Hval2 = array.get(CCI1H, 1)
            CCI1Hval3 = array.get(CCI1H, 0)
                if (CCI1Hval3 > CCI1Hval2 and CCI1Hval3 > CCI1Hval1)
                    label.new(bar_index, na, "CCI1H End", yloc = yloc.abovebar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal)
                else
                    array.shift(CCI1H)
else if cci < 50 
    array.clear(CCI1H)
```